# iOS and counterpart Complication not communicating with each other

Tags: swift, watchconnectivity, apple-watch-complication, wcsession

The basic concept of my App is that the Complication requests the iPhone for data and the iPhone then sends the data back.
I activate my WCSession from my iPhone App in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Also in my Watch app I've overwritten the `init()` from the ExtensionDelegate.

This is my singleton from the iPhone:

```
class WatchConnectivityManager: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {

   static let sharedManager = WatchConnectivityManager()

   private override init() {
       super.init()
   }

   private let session: WCSession? = WCSession.isSupported() ? WCSession.defaultSession() : nil

  func startSession() {
       print("session started")
       session?.delegate = self
       session?.activateSession()
   }

   func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
       print("didReceiveUserInfo")
       session.transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo(["reply":""])
   }
}
```

And this is my singleton from my Watch:

```
class WatchConnectivityManager: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {

   static let sharedManager = WatchConnectivityManager()

   private override init() {
       super.init()
   }

   private let session: WCSession? = WCSession.isSupported() ? WCSession.defaultSession() : nil

   func startSession() {
       print("session started")
       session?.delegate = self
       session?.activateSession()
   }

   func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
       print("didReceiveUserInfo")
   }

   func requestData() {
       print("data requested")
       session!.transferUserInfo(["request" : ""])
   }
}
```

In my ExtensionDelegate's init, which should be called when I activate my Complication I call the `startSession` and the `requestData` :

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

   override init() {
       WatchConnectivityManager.sharedManager.startSession()
       WatchConnectivityManager.sharedManager.requestData()
   }

   func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {}

   func applicationDidBecomeActive() {}

   func applicationWillResignActive() {}

}
```

And the AppDelegate from my iPhone:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    WatchConnectivityManager.sharedManager.startSession()
    return true
}
```

The output is simply:

```
session started
data requested
```

without the `didReceiveUserInfo` when I debug the Complication on a Simulator in XCode.